# Calculate $\int \frac{1}{x-\sqrt{x}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x-\sqrt{x}} \, dx$. Any ideas? Integration by parts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the substitution $ x = u^2 $ to get $ \displaystyle \int \frac{2u}{u^2 - u} \ du $, which is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = t^{2}$

Then $$I=\int \dfrac{dx}{x-\sqrt{x}}=\int \frac{2tdt}{t^{2}-t}=2\int\frac{dt}{t-1}=2ln|t-1|$$

Comment: You would then need to substitute $x$ back, as the initial integral wasn't in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = t^2$ and $dx = 2tdt$

$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{x}}dx = \int\frac{2t}{t^2-t}dt$
$ = \displaystyle \int\frac{2t-2+2}{t^2-t}dt = 2\int\frac{1}{t}dt+2\int\frac{1}{t.(t-1)}dt$

$ = \displaystyle 2\ln \left|t\right|+2\int\frac{1}{t-1}dt-2\int\frac{1}{t}dt$

$ = \displaystyle 2\ln \left|t\right|+2\ln \left|t-1\right|-2\ln \mid t \mid+C$

$ = \displaystyle 2\ln \mid \sqrt{x}-1\mid+C$